# Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed.error in Remote driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I try to using remote driver to execute my script.But i got below mentioned error and code also attached.kindly need help
//My Driver Code

```
WebDriver driver =null;
String NodeURL="http://localhost:5566/wd/hub"; 
DesiredCapabilities capability=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capability.setCapability("platform", Platform.ANY);
capability.setCapability("binary", "C:\\Users\\praveenraj.d\\AppData\\Local\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"); 
driver=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(NodeURL),capability);
```

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm getting the same issue but for Python

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, switching "binary" to "firefox_binary" fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the binary path to `"C:\\Users\\praveenraj\.d\\AppData\\Local\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"`